# The string describing the audience of this site begins with an uppercase letter

Tags: bug, status-completed, scope, tour

The [tour page](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site asserts:

> Information Security Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Information security professionals.

In its second appearance here, the word "information" should not be capitalized.

Indeed, for every other SE  site, the string describing its audience (available [through the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=!.UDMsvaYdFr.b0xP&run=true)) begins with a lowercase letter, so that it can be used in a sentence.

The same incorrect case is seen on the [list of all SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic):

[image: list]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops. Fixed now, though it will take a bit for the page caching to update to reflect the fix.